# Using an NPM module within Ionic 3/Angular 5 app

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am attempting to use an npm module, [pretty-file-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-file-icons), within my Ionic/Angular app.  From what I can tell, this module does not have typings.

I tried adding `declare module 'pretty-file-icons'` to **src/typings.d.ts** and then, within a component using:

```
import * as prettyFileIcons from 'pretty-file-icons';
export class HandoutsPage {
  constructor(public fileIcons: prettyFileIcons) {}
}
```

Using this, I get the error `Can't resolve all parameters for Handouts Page`.  I have found several help articles online for this, but they all seem to be for SystemJS but, as I understand it, that has been replaced by Webpack.

How do I import this module so that I can use it within components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import * as prettyFileIcons from 'pretty-file-icons';
```

> You should't inject it in the `constructor`, use it directly:

```
console.log(prettyFileIcons.getIcon('test.csv'));
console.log(prettyFileIcons.getIcon('test.csv', 'svg'));
console.log(prettyFileIcons.getIcon('.test', 'svg'));

// Prints:
// csv
// csv.svg
// unknown.svg
```